# How to set wallpaper on IOS Xcode Simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am working on the app that creates wallpapers with custom dynamic island for Iphone 14 Pro/Max - 15 Pro/Max. So I need to be able to set wallpapers on the simulator to test the functionality, as I do not have physical Iphone with dynamic island.

I know that there is some way to set wallpaper in simulator - PhotoLibrary - some photo - share button - use as wallpaper. But when I do such thing, there is only black screen that is set as wallpaper for both Lock Screen and home. I tried it on M1 Air, M1 Pro, Intel i7 - always the same thing.

[image: What I get]

No matter what picture in library I choose, it always sets to black.

Does anyone know how to fix it and how to successfully be able to set wallpapers on Iphone simulator? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like iOS Simulator does not support custom wallpaper.

In iOS 16.0 simulator,

- I tried it from photos app -> Use as Wallpaper that you mentioned.
- I also tried long pressing on lock screen -> adding new lock screen.

Still, its always a black screen while and after setting it as wallpaper.
I also tried restarting the simulator. yet it didn't reflect :(

But in the iOS 17.0 simulator,

- By long pressing on lock screen -> add new lock screen. I'm able to use the wallpapers that are provided by Apple.

But not able to set wallpaper from custom photos.

Although I couldn’t find any documentation from Apple that explicitly states that the iPhone Simulator does not support custom wallpapers.
Based on the iPhone Simulator behavior I believe it does not support custom wallpapers. *(Also there is no Wallpaper section in settings app like on a physical phone)*

If you need to test an app that uses custom wallpapers, you will need to use a physical iPhone and load your app in it.

P.S. I'm using MacbookPro 2019, intel i7, macOS 14.0 Sonoma

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer, it seems like there is no direct solution( But I have decided to create a test app with UIImageView set on the whole screen. So when I add an image to this UIImageView with photo library picker, it imitates wallpaper behaviour and looks the same. Not the most convenient solution, but for now, it seems like it is the only one

Comment: Cool! That works...at least for testing.
Ping the name of your app once its up in App Store. Will check it out. 